# Pulling a particular block from a text file

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing

I am trying to pull out a block of data from a huge text file which contains 1193373557 lines.

I am excluding the first 25 lines and the last 4 lines, and the more challenging job is that the remaining  block contains data which is made of 2 headers; I want to separate this data based on header of the file.

Example: `test.txt` (this file contains header1's and header2's data)

```
header1
------
----
----
----
header2
-----
----
----
---
```

Required output:

- `header1.txt`: inside this file, all lines should be there till the header2 starts
- `header2.txt`: all lines after header1 should print

Comment: should the output file *include* the header or not?

Comment: Also please post the first line of the second header and clarify whether that's unique or not. If not please add more context useful to identify that exact line, for example some lines before and after that line (the best option would be having the line number however).

Comment: header 1:->pattern 1 : "Reading input from PoolA_Rnase"
header 2:->pattern 2: "Reading input from PoolB_Rnase"

Comment: @AdityaK please [edit] your question to add extra information. It is easy to miss and hard to read in the comments. You need to show us an example that accurately represents your actual data and the output you want to see from it.

Answer (score 1):

For `header1.txt`:

```
sed -n '/^header1$/,/^header2$/{/^header2$/d;p}' file >header1.txt
```

- `/pattern1/,/pattern2/` this syntax of `sed` matches all between (and including) `pattern1` and `pattern2`.
- `/^header2$/d` this will delete the header2 line, because it's not needed.
- `p` the rest will be printed.

---

For `header2.txt`:

```
sed -n '/^header2$/,$p' file >header2.txt
```

- Similar to the first command, this matches from `header2` to the last line `$`.

Comment: tq sir,
can you help me to include the pattern,
pattern 1 : "Reading input from PoolA_Rnase"
pattern 2: Reading input from PoolB_Rnase""

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK:

```bsh
awk -v nlines=$(wc -l test.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1) '$0=="Reading input from PoolA_Rnase", $0=="Reading input from PoolB_Rnase" {if($0 != "Reading input from PoolB_Rnase") {print >"header1.txt"}} $0=="Reading input from PoolB_Rnase", NR==nlines-4 {print >"header2.txt"}' test.txt
```

AWK script expanded and commented:

- `nlines` contains the number of lines in the file, calculated via `$(wc -l test.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1)`.

```awk
$0=="Reading input from PoolA_Rnase", $0=="Reading input from PoolB_Rnase" { # if the current record is between a record matching "Reading input from PoolA_Rnase" and a record matching "Reading input from PoolB_Rnase" inclusive
    if($0 != "Reading input from PoolB_Rnase") { # if the current record doesn't match "Reading input from PoolB_Rnase"
        print >"header1.txt" # prints the record to header1.txt
    }
}
$0=="Reading input from PoolB_Rnase", NR==nlines-4 { # if the current record is between a record matching "Reading input from PoolB_Rnase" and the record number `nlines-4` inclusive
    print >"header2.txt" # prints the record to header2.txt
}
```

```
% cat test.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
line 11
line 12
line 13
line 14
line 15
line 16
line 17
line 18
line 19
line 20
line 21
line 22
line 23
line 24
line 25
Reading input from PoolA_Rnase
foo
foo
foo
Reading input from PoolB_Rnase
bar
bar
bar
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
% awk -v nlines=$(wc -l test.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1) '$0=="Reading input from PoolA_Rnase", $0=="Reading input from PoolB_Rnase" {if($0 != "Reading input from PoolB_Rnase") {print >"header1.txt"}} $0=="Reading input from PoolB_Rnase", NR==nlines-4 {print >"header2.txt"}' test.txt
% cat header1.txt 
Reading input from PoolA_Rnase
foo
foo
foo
% cat header2.txt 
Reading input from PoolB_Rnase
bar
bar
bar
```